# How to write scraped data to multiple columns in excel with pandas data frames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to scrape data to columns A, B, C and D?  At the moment it is scraping only in the same column Team and Team odds instead of Team, Team Odds, Lay Team and Lay odds.  How to fix scraping to same column instead of multiple where I am wanting to append this data. Thanks
###########################################################################################################################################################

```
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
service = Service('driver/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(webdriver_manager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get('https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/en/football-betting-1/13')
WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
element = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".name:nth-child(1) , bf-coupon-table:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(1) .matched-amount-value"))
print('h')

scroll = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".coupon-page-navigation__label--next")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", scroll)

try:
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#cookie-holder span").click()
except:
    pass

i = 1
while i < 2:
    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        #
        #bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > abf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a[class = 'coupon-page-navigation__link coupon-page-navigation__link--next']
        #driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > abf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a[class = 'coupon-page-navigation__link coupon-page-navigation__link--next']")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,  ".name:nth-child(1)")))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".name:nth-child(1) , bf-coupon-table:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(1) .matched-amount-value"))
        scroll = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".coupon-page-navigation__label--next")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", scroll)
        NextStory = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a')))
        match = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".name:nth-child(1)")

        matches = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "CSS_SELECTOR")

        Team1 = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".name:nth-child(1)")
        for value in Team1:
            print(value.text)

        BackOdds = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".coupon-runner:nth-child(1) .back-selection-button .bet-button-price")
        for value2 in BackOdds:
            print(value2.text)

        Team2 = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".name:nth-child(2)")
        for value1 in Team2:
            print(value1.text)

        LayOdds = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".coupon-runner:nth-child(1) .lay-selection-button .bet-button-price")
        for value3 in LayOdds:
            print(value3.text)
        #bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a
        driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a[class = 'coupon-page-navigation__link coupon-page-navigation__link--next']")

        WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,  "bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a[class = 'coupon-page-navigation__link coupon-page-navigation__link--next']")))

        NextStory.click()


        for match in matches:
            #print(match.text)
            driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a[class = 'coupon-page-navigation__link coupon-page-navigation__link--next']")
            WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a[class = 'coupon-page-navigation__link coupon-page-navigation__link--next']")))
            NextStory.click()
    except:
        i = 6
        print('error')
        pass

#PANDA'S SCRAPING TO EXCEL
########################################################################################################################################################################
ls = []

for value in Team1:
  df1 = ls.append(value.text)

for value2 in BackOdds:
  df2 = ls.append(value2.text)

for value1 in Team2:
  df3 = ls.append(value1.text)

for value3 in LayOdds:
  df4 = ls.append(value3.text)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=ls)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=ls)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=ls)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data=ls)
#print(df1)
#print(df2)
#print(df3)
#print(df4)

#df1.to_excel('output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet_name_1', startcol=1)
#df2.to_excel('output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet_name_1', startcol=2)
#df3.to_excel('output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet_name_1', startcol=3)
#df4.to_excel('output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet_name_1', startcol=4)

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet_name_1', startcol=2)
    df2.to_excel(writer, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet_name_1', startcol=2)
    df3.to_excel(writer, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet_name_1', startcol=3)
    df4.to_excel(writer, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet_name_1', startcol=4)

print('Script Completed')
```

Comment: Please post the whole code, with imports as well.
######################################################################

Comment: @Carapace https://pastebin.com/EMDTTSGp

Comment: Some packages are imported two or even three times and some are imported and not used at all. You should keep it clean. And why is `options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()` between imports lol

Comment: @Carapace Yeah I clean up those imports once script works

Comment: `df1.to_excel(writer, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet_name_1', startcol=2)`? Didn't you want `startcol=1`?

Comment: and also oyu don't actually store the text any where.

Comment: @chitown88 Yeah I wanted separate columns for each data list extracted.  I realize that setting columns individually for each list is probably not achievable the way I did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I probably wouldn't have done the code this way (I there's an api request to get the data, don't **need** to use Selenium, although Selenium will work [see sample of the data here](https://ero.betfair.com.au/www/sports/exchange/readonly/v1/bymarket?_ak=nzIFcwyWhrlwYMrh&alt=json&currencyCode=AUD&locale=en_GB&marketIds=1.203654726,1.203661020,1.203624993,1.203625083,1.203624903,1.203625174,1.203625272,1.203485266,1.203639904,1.203640012,1.203589403,1.203485160,1.203661200,1.203525014,1.203316876,1.203306984&rollupLimit=25&rollupModel=STAKE&types=MARKET_STATE,MARKET_RATES,MARKET_DESCRIPTION,EVENT,RUNNER_DESCRIPTION,RUNNER_STATE,RUNNER_EXCHANGE_PRICES_BEST,RUNNER_METADATA,MARKET_LICENCE,MARKET_LINE_RANGE_INFO) in nice json format). But this will get you the data into lists. Then use pandas to construct the dataframe.

**Code:**

```
...

try:
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#cookie-holder span").click()
except:
    pass


team1List = []
backOddsList = []
team2List = []
layOddsList = []

i = 1
while i < 2:
    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        #
        #bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > abf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a[class = 'coupon-page-navigation__link coupon-page-navigation__link--next']
        #driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > abf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a[class = 'coupon-page-navigation__link coupon-page-navigation__link--next']")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,  ".name:nth-child(1)")))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".name:nth-child(1) , bf-coupon-table:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(1) .matched-amount-value"))
        scroll = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".coupon-page-navigation__label--next")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", scroll)
        NextStory = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a')))
        match = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".name:nth-child(1)")

        matches = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "CSS_SELECTOR")

        Team1 = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".name:nth-child(1)")
        for value in Team1:
            print(value.text)
            team1List.append(value.text)
            
        BackOdds = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".coupon-runner:nth-child(1) .back-selection-button .bet-button-price")
        for value2 in BackOdds:
            print(value2.text)
            backOddsList.append(value2.text)

        Team2 = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".name:nth-child(2)")
        for value1 in Team2:
            print(value1.text)
            team2List.append(value1.text)

        LayOdds = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".coupon-runner:nth-child(1) .lay-selection-button .bet-button-price")
        for value3 in LayOdds:
            print(value3.text)
            layOddsList.append(value3.text)
        #bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a
        driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a[class = 'coupon-page-navigation__link coupon-page-navigation__link--next']")

        WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,  "bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a[class = 'coupon-page-navigation__link coupon-page-navigation__link--next']")))

        NextStory.click()


        for match in matches:
            #print(match.text)
            driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a[class = 'coupon-page-navigation__link coupon-page-navigation__link--next']")
            WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a[class = 'coupon-page-navigation__link coupon-page-navigation__link--next']")))
            NextStory.click()
    except:
        i = 6
        print('error')
        pass

#PANDA'S SCRAPING TO EXCEL
########################################################################################################################################################################
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
     'Team1':team1List,
     'Back Odds':backOddsList,
     'Team2': team2List,
     'Lay Odds': layOddsList})

df.to_excel('output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet_name_1', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
              Team1 Back Odds                  Team2 Lay Odds
0         FC Anyang       2.5        Daejeon Citizen     2.84
1   Seoul E-Land FC      2.82              Gyeongnam     3.25
2         MFk Snina      1.08              FC Kosice       25
3   Rimavska Sobota      1.01  DUKLA BANSKA BYSTRICA         
4        Nove Zamky      1.08                Samorin     12.5
..              ...       ...                    ...      ...
91          Denmark      1.47                Tunisia     1.54
92           Mexico      2.74                 Poland     3.25
93           France      1.22              Australia     1.28
94          Morocco       4.6                Croatia      5.6
95          Germany      1.36                  Japan     1.48

[96 rows x 4 columns]
```